# Parse a string to a DateTime object

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, date-format

I'm trying to parse a `String` into a `DateTime` object but it seems to always default the month to 1. So let's say I give it a string `30/05/1970` it ends up being converted to `DateTime` object with the month value equal to `1`.

Here's the code:

```
    public static DateTime ToDateTime(this String value, String format)
    {
        Contract.Requires(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value));
        Contract.Requires(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(format));

        DateTime date;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
        {
            return date;
        }           

        throw new ArgumentException("Input value is not a valid date.");
    }
```

Note that the format that is being passed to the method is `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using the wrong format specifier for months.

It is `MM` not `mm`. You are parsing months as minutes at the moment.

Use `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Comment: I've been stuck with this for like 2 hours! I tried all sorts of things but I never thought of changing the format. Thanks for pointing this out! Much appreciated :)

Comment: @Kassem: you should probably mark this as a correct answer then

Comment: @MiMo: Yup, I did. I just had to wait until StackOverflow allows it.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably specifying an incorrect format.

Do this instead

```
var dt= ToDateTime("30/05/1970", "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

And take a look at this: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/